# How to use a svg image on slider thumb shape in flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtBKx.png)

I need to make this ui in flutter. But I can't find any way to customize the thumb shape of Slider.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderTheme(
      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
          inactiveTrackColor: widget.inActiveTrackColor,
          trackShape: const RoundedRectSliderTrackShape(),
          activeTrackColor: Colors.orange,
          disabledActiveTickMarkColor: Colors.orange,
          disabledActiveTrackColor: Colors.amber,
          trackHeight: widget.trackHeight,
          overlayColor: Colors.purple.withAlpha(36),
          thumbShape: const RoundSliderThumbShape()),
      child: Slider(
        min: widget.min,
        max: widget.max,
        divisions: widget.divisions,
        onChanged: null,
        value: widget.value,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom thumb shape for the `Slider` widget in Flutter by extending the `SliderComponentShape` class and overriding the `paint` method.

```dart
class CustomSliderThumbCircle extends SliderComponentShape {
  final double thumbRadius;
  final int min;
  final int max;

  const CustomSliderThumbCircle({
    required this.thumbRadius,
    required this.min,
    required this.max,
  });

  @override
  void paint(
      PaintingContext context,
      Offset center, {
        Animation<double>? activationAnimation,
        Animation<double>? enableAnimation,
        bool? isDiscrete,
        TextPainter? labelPainter,
        RenderBox? parentBox,
        SliderThemeData? sliderTheme,
        TextDirection? textDirection,
        double? value,
        double? textScaleFactor,
        Size? sizeWithOverflow,
      }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;

    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
      style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: thumbRadius * .8, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
      text: '${getValue(value!)}',
    );

    TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
        text: span,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    tp.layout();
    Offset textCenter =
    Offset(center.dx - (tp.width / 2), center.dy - (tp.height / 2));

    canvas.drawCircle(center, thumbRadius, paint);
    tp.paint(canvas, textCenter);
  }

  int getValue(double value) {
    return min + (max - min) * value.round();
  }
}
```

You can then use this custom thumb shape in your `Slider` widget

```dart
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
    thumbShape: CustomSliderThumbCircle(thumbRadius: 20, min: 0, max: 100),
  ),
  child: Slider(
    value: _value,
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        _value = value;
      });
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: I did it with the same approach later.